# Django Pip install: place data_files in project root directory without using absolute path

Tags: python, django, pip, setup.py, data-files

I want to install data_files (in this case just one html file) into a project's root directory. I can do it if I set the path absolute like 'user/documents/app', but I need the data files to be installable wherever the person installing the app happens to have their project. If that makes sense. So, I've been troubleshooting how to find and execute the directory of the project path, but with no luck. See below. I'm trying to "pass in" the path_to variable in my data_file array, but its not working. Ideally I would like the data_files go to the user's templates directory.

```
  import os
  from setuptools import setup

  os.chdir(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), os.pardir)))

  _ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
  path_to = os.path.join(_ROOT, "styleguides")


  setup(
     name='styleguide',
     version='1.0',
     packages=['styleguide'],
     package_data={'styleguide': [
        'styleguides/styleguide.html',
     ]},
     include_package_data=True,
     data_files = [(path_to, ['styleguide/styleguides/styleguide.html']),],
     license='BSD License',
     classifiers=[
       'Environment :: Web Environment',
        'Framework :: Django',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License',
         'Operating System :: OS Independent',
         'Programming Language :: Python',
         'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
         'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.2',
         'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3',
         'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP',
         'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: Dynamic Content',
],
```

)

```
  This apps directory structure is:

  Project/
      styleguide/
          __init__.py
          styleguides/
              styleguide.html
```

Comment: I might be wrong but, isn't it the case that for the python file you're running the `./` is the path of its root?

Comment: so maybe just do this? data_files = [('./', ['styleguide/styleguides/styleguide.html']),],

Comment: Perhaps, search around I think when executing a `.py` you know its root path and thus can place the file in it's root wherever you want.

Comment: Ok, yeah I just tried the ./ example but no luck. thanks again for your help

Comment: Have you explored importing BASE_DIR from the projects settings file, and referencing that?

Comment: hey @PANDAStack hmm, yeah I think I would still run into the same issue. Plus, you can't import your app's BASE_DIR into a setup.py I don't think.